# Sharing partitions between Ubuntu and Kubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, kubuntu, sharing

I am a noob and have no experience with computers so maybe this is a stupid question. I replaced Windows with Ubuntu 16.04LTS a week ago. I want to have another installation for a rolling Ubuntu. So i decided to go with Kubuntu 17.10. For the original Ubuntu,I have made separate partitions for /opt, /usr and /usr/local. Is it okay if I use these 3 for new Kubuntu as well ? If so how do I do it ? 
Will the Kubuntu files conflict with the Ubuntu ones if this is done ?

Comment: I wouldn't do this, because, as you say, there may be conflicts. Each version of Ubuntu ships with it's own versions of software and binaries. So, if you have 16.04 and 17.10 sharing the same "/usr"  partition, and you do an update in 16.04, it will overwrite those files that 17.10 put there with older versions - which are not what 17.10 needs. So you'd possibly end up with some sort of frakenbuntu, but more likely something that breaks in wiered ways.

Comment: However, what I'd do in this case is to have a shared data partition for documents, media, and so on, which is perfectly safe.

Comment: First, there is no "rolling Ubuntu" or Kubuntu. Also, I am not sure why make so many separate partitions? None of those you've mentioned above are really necessary. Lastly, yes, you can use them, and all you need to do is install Kubuntu from Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. There is no need to make an installation DVD/USB, boot from it, etc. The Kubuntu files should not conflict, in fact, some of them are shared between all the *buntu flavors.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not advice it. Ubuntu and KUbuntu are having different shared librerys and programs (ones that are enviroment-releted). Installing them separatly would be much better idea. You can always make an experiment but I can't tell it what result you will get.
2. When it comes to separating system on several partitions it commes very handy to have /home, / and swap separated (you may reinstall system and have all data and settings as they were before). Unless you know exacly what and why are you doing there is no sense in futhurer seperation.